# Need help to identify minifigure

Tags: minifigure-identification, castle

Can someone help me to identify minifigure linked below:

I´ve been searching now about three hours without luck :)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Knight's Kingdom II - the guardian]

Knight's Kingdom II - the guardian (picture taken from bricklink)

http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=cas264

I searched on Bricklink catalog under, 'minifig leg assembly' using the keyword, 'brown,' using thumbnails.  Only had two pages to look through.